url slash problem, resulting in none of these file exits
i am creating a music player application, below is the code
export const playListData: Track[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Baila Conmigo',
        artist: 'Selena Gomez & Rauw Alejandro',
        album: 'Revelación',
        artwork:
          'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baila_Conmigo_%28Selena_Gomez_and_Rauw_Alejandro_song%29#/media/File:Selena_Gomez_and_Rauw_Alejandro_-_Baila_Conmigo.png',
        url: require('./assets/conmigo.mp3'),
      },


the error is saying the url does, not exists , on pc the url it shows, is .\assets\conmigo.mp3, but here i have to write this ./assets/conmigo.mp3  , and when i change it to this .\assets\conmigo.mp3, it does'nt change  please help me

This could be a metro bundle issue, check metro bundler config file..

metro bundler config file , is absolutely fine , I checked it

the in url was getting because of the spelling mistake, named the file assests, and in url had written assets, and the second problem was that, in the end i did'nt use the ; after ]
